# Can't ping a client PC from a Windows Server 2003 R2 Server SP2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, ping

I recently installed a Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2, for a Kronos Workforce Timekeeper Server.

Now, the server is able to connect to the internet, and I can ping its IP Ad from other PCs.

However, pinging other PCs from said Server gets me nothing. I also can't start a remote desktop session, despite the fact that it is enabled.

I haven't installed anything other than SP2, for IIS. Where do I start looking on what's wrong?

Additional Details:

- Firewall is disabled.
- Remote Assistance and Remote Desktop is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you can't ping I believe that the local firewall is blocking the connection or a routing problem. If possible try to trace the ping packet with Wireshark (or something else) and see if it gets to the server. Sometimes the connection going to the server is correct, but the configuration for the connection to return is sometime misconfigured (has happen to me).

Does the server happen to be on a different vlan? 
Use this command in cmd to check if the routing table on the server is correct: `netstat -rn`

Comment: Firewall is off (should've mentioned that in the question). `nestat -rn` returns a table of nertowk destinations.

Comment: If the routing table is correct. You will need to run a packet capture on the port the server is connected to and narrow down the issue.

Comment: If the server is on the same VLAN as the clients then the ARPs might not be getting to the server.